# Screen blinking loop when boot up

Tags: 18.04, nvidia-optimus

I reboot my computer, I am using Ubuntu 18.04, after I installed Nvidia driver and reboot, after that it is stuck at black screen, when I'm proceeding to tty2, tty3 and `ctrl+alt+F7`, screen blinks continuously and its hard to type because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all packages starting with nvidia-*. Then reboot. This will revert back to the nouveau driver, and you will be able to log into the desktop.

Here's how to do it:

1. On the black screen, press ctrl-alt-f2 to switch to the terminal.
2. Type `sudo apt purge nvidia-` and press tab twice. It will list all installed packages whose name start with nvidia-.
3. Remove each of those packages, using `sudo apt purge package-name1 package-name2 package-name3 etc`
4. Reboot, using the `reboot` command.

Also keep in mind that Nvidia Optimus doesn't work well on Ubuntu 18.04. You might have a better experience with the Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 20.04.

One last advice: If the problem persists on Ubuntu 20.04, try Ubuntu Mate 20.04. It seems to have better support (it was the only distro that worked with my notebook's GPUs out-of-the-box).